# Android glide remove / update image from cache

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

It's possible to update an image from the cache with Glide ? I tried this :

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(Uri.parse(url)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(mImage);
```

But there is a problem each time I'll scroll into my Listview, this will reload all images because I don't use the cache. So this is not the good way.

My problem is that I want to update an image from the cache my image has the same URL. How can I do to remove this image with this URL or update the image from the cache with this URL ?

Answer (score 0):

See Glide's wiki article on this topic here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation.